# Laptop does not use more than 50% of my 4GB RAM

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory

Recently in my laptop, I've noticed a change in speed I went to look task manager and saw that my computer would not go over 50% - 60% of memory even with firefox open 15 tabs each

After some researching, I checked how much memory is unusable in Resource Monitor... it shows that I have total 4GB of memory, Available 2GB, Chached 1.4GB

Physical Memory:

Hardware reserved: 57MB 
In Use: 1974MB
Modified: 39MB 
Standby: 1426MB 
Free: 700MB

Model: Lenovo G570 OS: Windows 10 Pro Version: 1709 System type: 64bit OS x64 based processor

So the problem is My laptop won't get enough memory so OS just turns off automatically after 10 mins.

Please Help Me

Comment: Why do you think your laptop turns off because of memory? The details you’ve provided show what appears to be perfectly acceptable numbers. What I see is a laptop that doesn’t need any more memory. Please explain the real problem. Windows doesn’t “turn off” because of memory.

Comment: @Appleoddity Because my laptop becomes too slow before it's going to turn off.

Comment: It sounds like the laptop is probably overheating. The slowness you experience is called throttling. Please get rid of whatever cause you’ve already come up with and describe the actual problem you are having if you want help. Your problem is “my laptop is slow and turning off” your problem is not “my laptop does not use more than 50% of 4GB.” That’s the point I’m trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about the RAM in your computer, theres a few way's to test it. The first is the Windows Memory Diagnostic which you can run by going to START > search for "Windows Memory Diagnostic" and click "Restart now and check for problems"

The other tool you can try to use is called Memtest86 which you can get here:[Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)

There are more detaileds instructions here: [HowToGeek- How to Test Your Computer’s RAM for Problems](https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/)